# How can I split a list into chunks using span?

Tags: haskell

Can I rewrite this using library functions?

```
chunks :: ([a] -> ([a], [a])) -> [a] -> [[a]]
chunks f [] = []
chunks f xs = case c of
  [] -> cs
  ys -> ys : cs
  where
    (c, rest) = f xs
    cs = chunks f rest
```

If I give it a `span`-like function that always takes at least one element off the list, it'll consume the list and return a list with sublists of the elements that were broken off each time the function was called.

Comment: You might also like the [split](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/split) package, which offers many ways to slice-and-dice lists... or one of the many parsing combinator libraries.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This looks very much like an unfold:

http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:unfoldr

Maybe something like (untested):

```
chunks f xs = unfoldr f' xs
  where f' [] = Nothing
        f' xs' = Just $ f xs'
```